SQL - What changed from listagg from Month to Month
I am using SQL and I have a list of products that I used SQL listagg to get all products (products are varchar and not numerical, used numbers as that was easier) that someone has on a monthly basis. Is there anyone to see what they added or subtracted month to month?
Desired Output:



Partner
Date
product
MoM Change (Expected Output Column)




A
2020-01
1,2,3,4
Null


A
2020-02
1,2,4
3



So far I have:
select partner, date, listagg(distinct product) within group (ORDER BY product)
from table

edit: the MoM change is the desired column and I am using snowflake sql, sorry about that! I am new to posting here and new to the data world!

listagg() is an Oracle function, not MySQL. Which DBMS are you actually using?

There's no partner column in the desired output, why do you have it in the query? And where is MoM Change in the query?

I am using snowflake as our data warehouse! I added in the partner in the sql query and the MoM change is the desired column

Your desired output is all messed up now. You have 1,2,3,4 in the Date column. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support for how to format tables in posts.

I appreciate the patience! I believe it is correct now!

You should also post the input data that produces this result. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Sample data (missing) and desired results would help us replicate. This can be solved by joining on month/product to month-1/product to surface the difference before aggregation.

I would treat this problem a little differently and avoid the listagg() altogether, if all you want to do is see the "ending" dates for the projects.
Usually this problem is found under "Consolidating overlapping time ranges" or the "Gaps and Islands Problem." Basically, you want to consolidate all customer-productid combos into a date range of when they were consecutively active, and then all you'd have to do is query the result for the end-date and you'd see partner A, Product 3, end date 2020-01

For the data shown - can you show us what output you expect?

So the first three columns are the fields that I have, and the MoM Change is my desired output
